# How to facilitate aync orchestration with sling jobs?

Tags: aem, sling

**Question in brief:**
Does AEM have a jobs orchestration API or approach via listeners or similar that will let the orchestrator know when a topic's jobs are completed?

**Question in detail:**
My first stack overflow post so be gentle. I have a scenario where a third party system is referenced each night by AEM via a scheduler, to identify any new closed user groups that need to be applied to specific folders in AEM. Then other CUGs are added to/removed from those folder-level CUGs.

The scheduler kicks off a job executor, and that job kicks off other jobs. So it's currently like this:

**CURRENT STATE:**
AEM Scheduler (nightly)

-- Job Executor

```
 -- Job Consumer 1: ordered queue, one job at a time. Around 1k jobs per run, takes hours.

 -- Job Consumer 2: unordered queue, these jobs run in parallel. Around 1k jobs, takes minutes.
```

Things are working ok now but because of the matrix nature of some of our data, the Job Consumer 1 topic's jobs have to be run ordered, in sequence. That takes a very long time to run, and I'm looking at ways to speed it up significantly.

One way to speed up Job Consumer 1 is to break up that consumer into two, with each being changed to run in parallel vs in sequence. BUT.... after breaking it up into two, I wouldn't be able to safely start the second set until the first set is done. Here's what it could look like:

**POSSIBLE FUTURE STATE:**
AEM Scheduler (nightly)

-- Job Executor

```
 -- Job Consumer 1: unordered queue

 -- Job Consumer 2: unordered queue, BUT MUST NOT START until all Job Consumer 1 jobs are done.

 -- Job Consumer 3: unordered queue, can run whenever
```

My challenge is the "BUT MUST NOT START until all Job Consumer 1 jobs are done" part. If this were Azure Functions I'd use an actual Orchestrator to do that. But in AEM, I don't see an orchestration tool to manage a job set. I'm thinking I can use a resource change listener, listening to deletes from the topic's /var/eventing tree. That should work but I'd only do that if there isn't a better way like a jobs orchestration tool that I haven't come across yet.

Hopefully my question is coming across. Thanks in advance.

Have a functioning solution, but would like to speed it up.